# Google Colab - How can I get rid of "FileNotFoundError" error for a function call?

Tags: ipython, google-colaboratory

As the title clearly describes the issue, I've been getting a `FileNotFoundError` error for a function call on `Google Colab`. You may find my script below. How can I resolve this issue? Any helps will be appreciated a lot.

```
def main():
    # some code


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error message:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-e292631388d3> in <module>()
    160 
    161 if __name__ == '__main__':
--> 162     main()

4 frames
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/content/<ipython-input-6-e292631388d3>'
```

Comment: Did you try to restart the runtime? Or to replicate it in another colab ipython file? I tried to replicate your error, but for me it worked just fine. My guess, based on the error, is that your runtime disconnected and for some reason (probably a bug), your .ipynb file was not sent to the instance of Google Cloud Engine that runs the code

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I've already restarted the runtime, but, unfortunately, this did not work. Replicating the ipython file in another colab did not work, as well.

Comment: Your question is not currently answerable, this is not all the code, and the traceback is incomplete, it makes no sense without all the information in the traceback.